# How do I install wxPython into a specific VsCode Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, wxpython

Running the latest VsCode under Windows 10, I have installed wxPython from a terminal window into the Python 3.6.3 standard environment (the one it mentions when I ask `python -V`).

Within VsCode, provided I select that environment (`Python 3.6.3 32-bit`), my application runs fine.

However, if I switch to either of my other two environments, `Python 3.6.6 64-bit` or `Python 3.7.2 32-bit`, the `import wx` fails, presumably because I haven't `pip install`-ed `wxPython` into those environments.

How do I do this, `pip install` a package into a *specific* environment configured in VsCode?

I see that, when VsCode *runs* my application, it does something like:

```
cd 'c:\Users\Pax\Documents\pysrc';
${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; &
    'C:\Users\Pax\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe'
    'c:\Users\Pax\.vscode\extensions\blah\blah\ptvsd_launcher.py'
    '--default' '--client' '--host' 'localhost' '--port' '53664'
    '-m' 'myapp.py'
```

Do I need to do something similarly opaque when running `pip`?

Comment: How do you manage your environments? Using `conda` or directly create it using VsCode?

Comment: @Sraw, I don't (knowingly) use Conda. I'm pretty sure I had at least one environment installed when I installed VsCode, though it *could* have been more. The other two *may* have been added later, and picked up by VsCode.

Comment: Well as I don't know how do you organize your environments, it is difficult to give an exact solution. There is a simplest one: If you can execute those two python environments no matter through the built-in terminal in VsCode or normal terminal, you should be able to install `wxPython` into corresponding environment by `python -m pip install wxPython`.

Comment: @Sraw, thanks heaps for your help, I managed to find a solution before I got a chance to try yours out, by running the specific `pip` for the environment. It appears from testing that running the specific `python` to run the specific `pip` also works so, if you'd like to post that as an answer, it's worth some rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to install it into *each* Python environment where you want to use it.

Assuming you're using a standard setup, this is probably as simple as:

```
C:\Users\Pax\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe install wxpython
```

This will `pip install wxpython` into the *specific* environment (Python 3.7 in this case) and allow you to use it from within the Python code running inside VsCode.

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to use `pip3` instead of `pip` in my Terminal in Linux Mint 19.